# what is causing my camera to not rotate on the Y axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine

im making a camera movement script for a unity game but i cant look horrizontally. i can looks up and down just fine. im not sure what specifically is wrong but i bet its an incorrect number somewhere

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class looking : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    private float xRotation = 0f;
    private float yRotation = 0f;
   

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseY);

        yRotation = mouseX;
        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0f, 0f);
        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

ive tried swapping x and y arround with no effect

Comment: `player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseY);` should be `player.Rotate(Vector3.left* mouseY);`

Comment: Your code doesn't show the relationship between `transform` and `player` but you have some odd lines of code.  You are setting `transform.localRotation` twice.  The second is overwriting the first.